# MotionLayout: views Included in a layout are invisible when relaunch onCreate()

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

Included views are not displayed after first launching a screen.

Video of reproducing:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EzNe5kXHZ_91kycYsZ8RlcEDZwX3EEyv

Main layout:
https://gist.github.com/albka1986/9028905ece74d2e58d5fca7afd796732

Scene:
https://gist.github.com/albka1986/f17a538980aa02001094df99eec775ba

Version:
'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha5'

Answer (score 0):

The bug have been fixed in 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1'.

Now I can't reproduce it anymore.